# What is the nfds from select() used for

Tags: c, select

I was wondering what the `nfds` does, after reading different manuals, I end up with the only answer being *it is the highest numbered file descriptor plus one*. What is it exactly used for?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7742/whats-the-purpose-of-the-first-argument-to-select-system-call

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you're using [`select()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html), you are trying to check the status of a set of file descriptors.  The possible range of file descriptors you're interested in ranges from a low of 0 (standard input) to some maximum value (the highest file descriptor you have open that you're interested in checking the status of).  You have to tell `select()` how big the list of file descriptors is because the total number can be 'vast' (32767, for example).  In that case, it takes time for the kernel to process the descriptors, plus you may not have initialized the `fd_set` up to that number of entries.  `FD_SETSIZE` also figures in the equation, but sometimes you can change that value.

So, if you want to monitor file descriptors 24-31, you'd set `nfds` to 32, and ensure that you use `FD_ZERO()` to zero the whole `fd_set` and `FD_SET()` to set entries 24-31.  Note, too, that `select()` modifies the input parameters, so you have to use `FD_ISSET()` to test after the `select()` returns, and in general you have to redo the initialization (or copy a saved value) of `fd_set` before calling `select()` again.

Comment: From the name `nfds` ( *number of file descriptors* ) I would have expected `7` when I want to monitor fd number `24` to `31`. Why `32` ? (I know you are right, the man page says that too, but I'm wondering why)

Comment: @hek2mgl: It's because the set starts at file descriptor 0; there is no way in the interface to specify another starting point. That can slow things down if you are using `select()` in a server with thousands of open file descriptors.

Comment: Downvoted: even if the answer is (mostly) correct, it misses critical details and is worded in a way which is impossible to understand. Please see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7742/whats-the-purpose-of-the-first-argument-to-select-system-call instead.